# Is it bad to call ffi.load multiple times on the same library?

Tags: lua, luajit

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that only the first call to ffi.load loaded the library, subsequent calls to the function during the lifetime of a process would essentially be a no-op. Is there someway to verify this?

```
local ffi = ffi.require("ffi")

local _M = {
  lib = nil
}

function _M.load_library(path)
  _M.lib = ffi.load(path)
end
```

Comment: Benchmarking. Source code. Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `_M.lib == nil` whenever you want.